# Ember JS for SCORM Compliance

Tags: ember.js, scorm

Is there any references that explain how to make Ember JS Learning Content that will be used in the LMS (SCORM Compliance). I've already tried to ember build and put the imsmanifest.xml on the root folder(/dist). When I upload all the /dist folder's content to the LMS (cloud.scorm.com), the Ember JS app is not shown.

Is there any suggestion to make learning content using SCORM Compliance and Ember JS? I will use SCORM 2004 4th Edition. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure how much this will help, So I am not posting this as an answer, but you may want to compare your lesson setup with that from : https://github.com/adlnet/Starting-from-SCORM-A-Developers-Guide/blob/master/Instructions.md as SCORM can be a bit picky

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options -

1. Is this untracked?  Within the imsmanifest.xml you would label it's resource scormType as 'asset' or 'sco'.  Hint: If you have no SCORM communication included within your EmberJS content, then its a asset.
2. If its tracked, you should set its resource scormType as "sco".  This imply's your content is doing base things like Initializing and Terminating with the SCORM Runtime API (which in SCORM 2004 is the API_1484_11).

Example: https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/blob/master/imsmanifest.xml

If this is the first time your hearing about the API, you'll need to consider what your goals are.  Commonly curriculum will identify what data points are acceptable within your Shareable Content Object.  You must Initialize and Terminate at minimum, but if you opt to track Score, Progress, Completion Status you'll need to integrate that into your existing work.

There are free JavaScript libraries available for interacting with the SCORM Runtime API.  These will be called "SCORM Wrappers", "SCORM Content API" and there job is to locate the API_1484_11, and then begin to make Initialize, GetValue/SetValue, Terminate calls as needed.  These libraries will range in features and functionality since the SCORM spec has been around since 2001+ and then enhanced in 2004.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i think i've got your point to make the EmberJS and the scorm api doesn't crash, and i will make it tracked, but how to make Ember JS run on the LMS server, because as i know, the EmberJs project needs server to run. Thank you very much

Comment: Most LMS platforms will provide the API_1484_11 runtime before launching your content.  Your content would need to connect to it, and then begin to communicate with it.  This is done using a strategy to drill down thru the DOM and find the variable exposed.  If your building a LMS, then you'd need to construct the Runtime API based on the SCORM white papers, or purchase a solution.  Free options that support SCORM 1.2 would be like Moodle for example.  But it does not support SCORM 2004.